# Author (Year) for reference without natbib package for beamer

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, babel

I want reference icons on my reference so I disable `\usepackage{natbib}` on my beamer. Since then it gives me the reference icons on my reference but the citation has changed from `Author (Year)` to `[Author, Year]`
as you can see it in my MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% begin bib
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade49,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1949",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
    @article{greenwade79,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1979",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
    @book{goossens86,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1986",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
%end bib
%\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

I do not want this style \cite{goossens86}\\ nor \cite{greenwade79}

\end{frame}
%%bib config 

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{~}
    \frametitle[]{~}
    \def\newblock{}
    %\begin{block}[allowblockbreaks]{~}
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**I want to retain the reference icons while my citation is in the form of `Author (Year)`**

Comment: If you need clarification lat me know

Comment: Still on it, I have not got a headway